# How to parse simple JSON Array from URL?

Tags: java, android

I want to parse the simple array in a ListView.
my JSON Array looks like

```
["Java","PHP",".NET","Python"]
```

Comment: Search on GOOGLE.

Comment: use for loop to loop the array  and the String val = jsonarray,get(i);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code..

```
        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsonStr); // define json data
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            String data = jsonarray.get(i).toString();
            Log.d("Data",data);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> stringArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
    android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);

    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(str);
        for(int i = 0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
        {
            arrayList.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
        }
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: str here is array value u want to parse